# Worklight v6 - Build Environment and Project Builders

Tags: eclipse, ant, ibm-mobilefirst, worklight-studio

Migrating from Worklight Studio 5.0.6 to 6.0

We observe a small, but undesirable, difference in behaviour, or maybe a confiuguration chenge is needed somewhere we failed to find.

In v5.0.6 when one selects an environment and requests Build Environment and Deploy, the project's Builders are first executed. In v6.0 this does not appear to be the case, unless there's a option somewhere ...

The use case is that we have some pre-processing carried out by an ant task installed as a project builder. In v6.0 we now need to rememeber to run a Build Project and then build the environment.

Is there an option to control this behaviour?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an open defect in Worklight 6.0.0.x and 6.1.0.x.

There is currently no workaround for it.

Comment: Please see the below answer by CarmelB; my answer is no longer valid.

Answer (score 2):

this is how to run ant task in worklight 5.0.x - 6.x:

1. create the Ant file (build.xml):
   [image]
2. Navigate to project->properties->Builders->new->Ant Builder. press ok
3. in "Main" tab set the name for the builder and choose your Ant file (build.xml):
   [image]
4. in "Targets" tab choose when to run the Ant file (in this exemple in Auto Build):
   [image]
5. press OK
6. press OK
7. run "Build All and Deploy":

Success:
[image]